# Mapping Foreign Key in EF5.0

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

I have the below tables as my entities

```
public class Customer
{
  public int CustId{get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}


public class Address
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
   **public virtual Customer Customer {get;set;}**
}
```

In my model configuration for Address using Fluent API. I have the below code

```
HasKey(p => p.Id);
HasRequired(p => p.Customer).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("CustId"));
```

What I really want is instead of using 
   **public virtual Customer Customer {get;set;}** 
  I want to have Public Int CustID; property in Address Class... and still do the mapping
   as foreign key.

Could someone please throw some suggestions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the property to your Address class:

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CustId { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

and then update your fluent, instead of using the .map function use the .HasForeignKey function:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Customer)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CustId);
```

Comment: So when I need to save Address I can just use Address add= new Address(); add.custId = 123; add.save();

Comment: Yep! That will work, when you call SaveChanges() ef will automatically 'fix' the relationships and attach the customer object.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use DataAnnotations:

```
public class Address
{
    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustId")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```